# How to send a BSC token to an address?

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, binance-smart-chain

I am able to transfer BNBs from one address to another using this code sample.

However, I want to send a specific BSC tokens to another address. What should the parameters be?

```
const [transferInfo, setTransferInfo] = React.useState({
    to: '0x987ffbf3f7cdabb38782b9886d257ce74f338da5',
    amount: '0.01',
    txHash: ''
  })
```

How do I specify the BSC token parameter here.

Here is the original code from github.
https://github.com/ObsidianLabs/bsc-dapp-example/blob/master/src/App.js